# Why margins of such a box containing a in-flow box collapse

Tags: css

Here are my test code:

```css
.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  padding-top: 0.1px;
  border: solid;
}
.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 100px;
  background: pink;
}
.div3 {
  overflow: visible;
}
.div4 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p>sample 1</p>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2"><div class="div3"></div></div>
</div>
<hr />
<p>sample 2</p>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2"><div class="div4"></div></div>
</div>
```

According to the spec:

> top and bottom margins of a box that does not establish a new block formatting context and that has zero computed 'min-height', zero or 'auto' computed 'height', and no in-flow children

margins of both div2 may not collapse. However, in sample 2, margins didn't collapse as I thought, but they collapse in sample 1. So why?

---

According to BoltClock's explanation, margins in sample 1 collapse because the in-flow child(i.e. div3) don't establish a new BFC. I tried another test:

```css
.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  padding-top: 0.1px;
  border: solid;
}
.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 100px;
  background: pink;
}
.div5 {
  overflow: visible;
  float: left;
/*  position: absolute;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2"><div class="div5"></div></div>
</div>
```

With `float` value other than `none`, div5 establish a new BFC, so margins of div5 may not collapse accordingly. But they collapse unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> **Note** the above rules imply that:
>
> - A box's own margins collapse if the 'min-height' property is zero, and it has neither top or bottom borders nor top or bottom padding, and it has a 'height' of either 0 or 'auto', and it does not contain a line box, **and all of its in-flow children's margins (if any) collapse**.

Emphasis mine.

In sample 2, div4 establishes a new block formatting context. As a result, its own margins are not adjoining (i.e. it does not meet the condition that you have quoted), and so they cannot collapse. Because div4's margins do not collapse, the margins of its own div2 parent cannot collapse through it. As a result, none of the positive margins in sample 2 collapse.

---

Floating an element takes it out of the flow, so the margins of div2 in your new test are able to collapse because it has no in-flow children.

Answer (score 0):

This is very interesting question. I never faced with this before, but now, according to some articles I found that some situation prevents margin collapsing:

http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/

- floated elements
- absolutely positioned elements
- inline-block elements
- elements with overflow set to anything other than visible (They do
  not collapse margins with their children.)
- cleared elements (They do not collapse their top margins with their parent block’s bottom margin.)
- the root element

Apparently overflow prevent margin collapsing not only if it is applied on parent element ;)

From other article I saw, that this effect is used in several micro clearfix.